# Why do we get the following error for the dependency we have used for pdfview

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-studio

This is the error for the dependency we have used for pdfview

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:D:/6th Sem/BookTrial/app/build.gradle">app</a>
```

We have stored the pdf on **firebase** and then this error has occurred while using the pdfview

Also, we have Updated the Android Studio to the latest version, which somehow has caused this error

Answer (score 1):

These two libraries are available in jcenter repository only:

1. The stable one

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

2. And one you have used

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

As a result, it will display an error since it is shutting down. So you should try [PdfiumAndroid](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid), Since it is available in both jcentre as well as maven.

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.9.0'
```